# Blazor SSR .Net 8 Redirect to a shered project Page component fails when reloading page or hotreload

Tags: blazor-server-side, server-side-rendering, .net-8.0

I have created a solution has blazor SSR project and another project which will be shared between all the projects (Razor class library) it will contain all shared components and pages
and this approach was working fine in .Net 6 & 7 now in .Net 8 I am facing the following issues

- when a page component is included inside the shared project and redirect to it it opens very well but if I want refresh the page or hot reload it gives

> This localhost page can’t be found

[image]

Although this issue doesn't happen when the page is included in the SSR project
following is github link for the test solution
[Github Repo](https://github.com/salghazaly/SSR_Test)